# How do I use config.log_tags with Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've added `config.log_tags = [:uuid, :remote_ip]` to my `development.rb`, `test.rb` and `production.rb` files and I do get to see those fields when I run locally (development).

However, when I deploy to Heroku, it looks like the standard logging takes over and I don't see my additional fields. Other changes in the same deploy did happen so I guess Heroku overrides my logging config (like it does with the database config).

Any idea how I can still add those fields to the log?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a heroku restart? The solution below works for me on Rails 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post on heroku's blog](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/2/28/http_request_id_s_improve_visibility_across_the_application_stack) about using HTTP Request IDs, which states:

> HTTP Request IDs are now enabled on all Heroku apps.

They just enabled this feature (as of Feb '14) on their platform so you should be able to see the UUID/x-Request-ID in your logs now. This should do the trick in your `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.log_tags = [ :uuid ]
```

You can read more details on this in the [heroku dev center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-request-id#usage-with-rails).